# Problem on subfigure 2X2

Tags: floats, subcaption

I try to put figures in 2X2, but they appear in 4 rows.

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/mean/N14.png}
    \caption[Network2]%
    {{\small Network 1}}    
\label{fig:mean and std of net14}
\end{subfigure}
\quad
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}  
 \centering 
        \includegraphics[scale=0.29]{images/mean/N24.png}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small Network 2}}    
        \label{fig:mean and std of net24}
        \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}   
 \centering 
        \includegraphics[scale=0.29]{images/mean/N34.png}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small Network 3}}    
        \label{fig:mean and std of net34}
        \end{subfigure}
        \quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}   
 \centering 
        \includegraphics[scale=0.29]{images/mean/N44.png}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small Network 4}}    
        \label{fig:mean and std of net44}
        \end{subfigure}


        \caption[ The average and standard deviation of critical parameters ]
        {\small The average and standard deviation of critical parameters: Region R4} 
        \label{fig:mean and std of nets}
        \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Each of your `\subfigure`s is `1\textwidth` wide - there's no way LaTeX could fit two of these in a row. Also you don't need the minipage there.

Try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Example-Image}
            \caption[Network2]%
            {{\small Network 1}}    
            \label{fig:mean and std of net14}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}  
            \centering 
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Example-Image}
            \caption[]%
            {{\small Network 2}}    
            \label{fig:mean and std of net24}
        \end{subfigure}
        \vskip\baselineskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
            \centering 
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Example-Image}
            \caption[]%
            {{\small Network 3}}    
            \label{fig:mean and std of net34}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
            \centering 
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Example-Image}
            \caption[]%
            {{\small Network 4}}    
            \label{fig:mean and std of net44}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption[ The average and standard deviation of critical parameters ]
        {\small The average and standard deviation of critical parameters: Region R4} 
        \label{fig:mean and std of nets}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2x2 output]

Of course you would drop the `\usepackage{mwe}` and substitute your pictures back in at appropriate scaling.

Comment: Thanks, but when I am using these two packages mwe, and subcaption, I get this error: ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.Any idea please?

Comment: @Maryam did you try running the exact code from my example? That compiles fine for me on a clean TeXLive 2014. Otherwise do make sure all `\usepackage` are before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Maryam the `mwe` package was only to get the sample images..

Comment: You don't actually need to add `\usepackage{mwe}` explicitly to use those images, as long as the package is installed they're available.

Comment: It works nice, but how to use `float` option `[H]`?

Comment: Turns out that the \hfill is important.

Comment: I had to change the `\quad` after the third subfigure to `\hfill`, otherwise the lower left figure wouldn't be aligned, but offset to the left.

Comment: that makes sense - quad is a fixed space, so alignment would be off (actually visible in the picture if you check carefully). this was an error in the original answer it seems - i edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This also worked for me:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-8em}{0em}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:}
  \end{subfigure}
  %
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{adjustwidth}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-8em}{0em}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:}
  \end{subfigure}
  %
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/.png}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

your solution was very helpful.

note that it only works with `\usepackage{changepage}`.

I think you should include it in your answer.

Thanks again,
Nadav A

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/218889)