# Problem in putting figures in 2X2 using subfigure

Tags: floats

I used this code:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figs/fig7.eps}
        \caption[Network2]%
        {{\small Network 1}}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net14}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figs/fig8.eps}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small Network 2}}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net24}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figs/fig9.eps}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small Network 3}}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net34}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figs/fig10.eps}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small Network 4}}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net44}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[ The average and standard deviation of critical parameters ]
    {\small The average and standard deviation of critical parameters: Region R4}
    \label{fig:mean and std of nets}
\end{figure*}
```

But I don't know why in the line

```
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Figs/fig7.eps}
```

and the other three similar lines for fig8, fig9 and fig10 I have the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero
```

I do not know what's the problem.

Comment: Couple of points. 1. Next time, please provide an MWE. 2. I'd use `\subcaptionbox` of the subcaption-pkg for constructions such as this one, it is *way* more comfortable. It's only `\subcaption{Caption text.}{Path to image file}` That's it! 3. You can also globally define the text size of *all* captions in your document. Either use the built-in commands of KOMA (in case you use a KOMA class) or the `caption`-package. 4. You do not need to give the lof-brackets (`[]`) for the `\caption`-command.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196481/problem-on-subfigure-2x2

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the problem you get; however, you should realize that inside `subfigure`, `\textwidth` refers to the size reserved for the whole subfigure, so you want `width=\textwidth` or the image will be further halved down.

Also don't use `\small` inside `\caption`, but better change the layout with `\captionsetup`.

Don't say `\vskip\baselineskip`, but `\bigskip` or `\vspace{...}` preceding it with a blank line.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\captionsetup{font=small}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figs/fig7.eps}
\caption{Network 1}
\label{fig:mean and std of net14}
\end{subfigure}%
%
\hfill
%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figs/fig8.eps}
\caption{Network 2}
\label{fig:mean and std of net24}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip 

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figs/fig9.eps}
\caption{Network 3}
\label{fig:mean and std of net34}
\end{subfigure}%
%
\hfill
%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figs/fig10.eps}
\caption{Network 4}
\label{fig:mean and std of net44}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{The average and standard deviation of critical parameters: Region R4}
\label{fig:mean and std of nets}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `subfigure` in your MWE, so I propose another possibility to arrange `subfigures`. In such cases I rather use `subfig` package:

```
documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[labelsep=space,
                labelfont={sf,bf},
                textfont=sf]{subfig}
    \usepackage[labelsep=colon,
                labelfont={sf,bf},
                textfont=sf]{caption}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% just for generating 
                                             % provided image
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}\centering
\subfloat[Network 1 \label{fig:mean and std of net14}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[Network 2 \label{fig:mean and std of net24}]
         {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}

\subfloat[Network 2 \label{fig:mean and std of net34}]
         {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[Network 1 \label{fig:mean and std of ne44}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
\caption[The average and standard deviation of critical parameters]
        {The average and standard deviation of critical parameters: Region R4}
    \label{fig:mean and std of nets}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Avoid commands that are not documented in LaTeX; instead of `\vskip\baselineskip` use `\bigskip` with a blank line before it (and one following will also visually represent the skip).

Comment: I agree. I just copied this from given MWE without any thinking. I edit my answer.