# Latex Subfigures (2x2) full width

Tags: floats, subfloats

I need a subfigure (2x2) for a scientifix paper! The figures are made in matplotlib.pyplot (pdf, figsize=(14, 7)). Under each subfigure should be a label (a), (b), (c), (d).

I would like to scale them in a way, so that the subfigure covers the whole width.

Would be great if you could help me (or provide me a template/link) :)

Comment: Which document class do you use? (Not all subfigure-related packages and macros are compatible with all document classes...) Also, what are some of the formatting aspects -- e.g., one-column or two-coiumn?; width and height of textblock? -- of your document?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I use the "elsarticle" documentclas. I would like to have 2 columns (similar to: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LbOaj.png)

Comment: It is unclear what your problem really is. By two columns I think Mico meant whether the document has two columns. Can you give us a minimal working example of what you've tried so far, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` so we could try and see why your figures do not come out the way you want them to? Also why is this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196483/90297 not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions, in no particular order:

- Use a `figure*` environment to span both columns of text.
- Use `subfigure` environments to encase the graphs and associated captions. Choose the widths of the subfigures to satisfy your preferences and requirements. (For the code below, I've assume the four graphs are stored in files named `a.pdf`, `b.pdf`, `c.pdf` and `d.pdf`.)
- Use another `\caption` command to describe the overall contents of the figure.

---

```
% Select '5p' or '3p' option according to your journal's requirements.
% Omit the 'demo' option in real document.
\documentclass[3p,twocolumn,demo]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{lipsum}    % "\lipsum" for filler text
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for "\includegraphics" macro
\usepackage{subcaption}% for "subfigure" environment
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3] % filler text

\begin{figure*}  % spans both columns
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.pdf}
\caption{Network 1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill % maximize the horizontal distance between the graphs
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b.pdf}
\caption{Network  2}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip  % some extra vertical whitespace
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c.pdf}
\caption{Network  3}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill % maximize the horizontal distance between the graphs
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{d.pdf}
\caption{Network  4}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Averages and standard deviations} % Overall figure caption
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[4-17] % more filler text

\end{document}
```