# Inserting 4 subfigures on one page

Tags: floats, subfloats

[image]

Does any one have a clue how to include four subfigures on one page like this at a good scale so that all graphs are visible. So far I have resorted to putting two sufigures in one figure because overleaf is too fidgity.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{PMMA_StressStrain.eps}
  \captionof{figure}{PMMA Stress Strain Curves}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Nylon_StressStrain.eps}
  \captionof{figure}{Nylon 6 Stress Strain Curves}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Steel_StressStrain.eps}
  \captionof{figure}{Steel Stress Strain Curves}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Al_StressStrain.eps}
  \captionof{figure}{Al Stress Strain Curves}
  \label{fig:5}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Does [Latex Subfigures (2x2) full width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335524/5001) help?

Comment: No not really. I have a diffierent document class so it doesn't work.

Comment: And what would that document class be?

Comment: Please also clarify what kind of captions and figure numbers you would like toget? The image shows subfigures (e.g. a), b), ... for the individual figures, in combination with a common caption for all of them?), while the code produces 4 figures, each with their own caption (e.g. figure 1, figure 2,...)