# How to place four images without spaces between in a 2x2 rectangle?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

Problem: there should be no space between the images. But there is.

Code ([fair use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196483/145593)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{{\small Network 1}}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{frog.jpg}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net14}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\columnwidth}  
        \centering
        \caption{{\small Network 1}}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{frog.jpg}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net24}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\columnwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{frog.jpg}
        \caption{{\small Network 1}}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net34}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\columnwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{frog.jpg}
        \caption{{\small Network 1}}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net44}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption[ The average and standard deviation of critical parameters ]
    {\small The average and standard deviation of critical parameters: Region R4} 
    \label{fig:mean and std of nets}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Here is how it looks (using Overleaf):
[image: Using Overleaf: result]

How it should look like (without frames, of course):
[image: How it should look like]

Comment: `\end{subfigure} \hfill\begin{subfigure}` adds a normal inter-word space plus whatever space `\hfill` expands to between the figure, you want `\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}` if you want no space (and make them .5 textwidth wide not .49

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried, but it doesn't work. The images suddenly place beneath one another instead of in a block. And even with the width .49, there is a space between the upper row and the lower row ... (I have deleted \quad too).

Comment: yes I only addressed the horizontal space, you get a vertical space because of `\vskip\baselineskip` which adds a vertical space

Comment: You provide `\label`s to the subfigures.  Can one assume that you need to be able to later `\ref` the subfigure, and not just the overall figure?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I would prefer to be able to refer to the subimages as well. If that isn't possible, well, I can just refer to the overall figure. But it would be better if I could refer to the subfigures. kr

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, updated the code to what you said. I still have the same problem. The question is edited regarding to your comment. Kind regards

Comment: If you can't resolve otherwise, this gives it, with primitive ability to reference subfigures, as shown: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\placeimg[1]{\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}
\centering
\tabbedShortstack{%
  (a) Cap 1 & (b) CAP2\strut\\
  \placeimg{A} & \placeimg{B} \\
  \placeimg{C} & \placeimg{A} \\
  (c) Cap 3 & (d) CAP4\strut
}
\caption{Overall caption\label{fg:4x}}
\end{figure}
In figure \ref{fg:4x}c, we find the letter ``C.''
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this

[image]

inserting subfigures inside a `tabular` where space between columns (`@{}`) and rows (`\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}`) is suppressed and eliminating some spurious spaces with `%` symbol.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
    \begin{tabular}{c@{}c}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{{\small Network 1}}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{frog.jpg}%
        \label{fig:mean and std of net14}
    \end{subfigure}&
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\columnwidth}  
        \centering
        \caption{{\small Network 1}}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{frog.jpg}%
        \label{fig:mean and std of net24}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\columnwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{frog.jpg}%
        \caption{{\small Network 1}}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net34}
    \end{subfigure}&
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\columnwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{frog.jpg}%
        \caption{{\small Network 1}}
        \label{fig:mean and std of net44}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption[ The average and standard deviation of critical parameters ]
    {\small The average and standard deviation of critical parameters: Region R4} 
    \label{fig:mean and std of nets}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```